# PHP validation - Is another way to validating the $int variable?

Tags: php, validation

I want to validate a variable that is integer or array of integer, a way is :

```
$int = 5; // or use [1, 5, 9] instead of 5
// $int = [1, 5, 9];
if (is_array($int)) {
    // statement if $int is an array
} elseif (intval($int) > 0) {
    $int = [$int];
    // statement if $int is an integer number
} else {
    ...
}
```

**Is another way to validating the $int variable?**

Comment: No anybody to answer me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An other way is :

```
$int = ['number_s' => 5]; // or use [1, 5, 9] instead of 5
// $int = ['number_s' => [1, 5, 9]];
$validateRules = [
    'number_s' => [
        'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        'flags' => FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY,
        // options
    ]
];
$validated = filter_var_array($int, $validateRules);
// now I can use $validated['number_s']
```